# Using NDepend, how can we removed Cycle Dependencies generated by the compiler due to Tasks (TPL) from the Dependency Matrix?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, ndepend

Using NDepend, how can we removed Cycle Dependencies generated by the compiler due to Tasks (TPL) from the Dependency Matrix.

If we cannot remove them, then how can we easily differentiate them from important cycle dependencies that need our attention.

Are there any best practices around dealing with compiler generated cycle dependencies?

### Edit:

The compiler generated dependency cycle can be observed in the top left of the diagram

[image: The compiler generated dependency cycle can be observed in the top left of the diagram]

Code that generates a Dependency Cycle (Compiles in .Net 4.0)

*logger is a field in my class

```
  private void WriteJsonFileToDiskAsync(string filePath, string json)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WriteJsonFileToDisk(filePath, json))
            .ContinueWith(HandleWriteException);
    }

    private void WriteJsonFileToDisk(string filePath, string json)
    {
        Stream fileStream = null;
        try
        {
            fileStream = File.Create(filePath);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                fileStream = null;
                writer.Write(json);
            }

            logger.InfoIfDebuggerIsAttached(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Persisted file: {0}", filePath));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
                fileStream.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static void HandleWriteException(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            //TODO: Handle Exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question would need to be refined with an example of what you call *Cycle Dependencies generated by the compiler due to Tasks (TPL)*. A .NET Reflector screenshot of the example + a second screenshot of corresponding NDepend Dependency Matrix would be needed for a clear answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to reproduce and post the screen shots.

Comment: Patrick, I have added more information. Is this sufficient to help me get a some sort of an idea of what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexandre, after compiling your source code, I obtain the following dependency Matrix:

[image]

We can see that the compiler generated a sub type declared inside `Program` from you. This generated type, named `Program+<>c__DisplayClass1` is just compiler gymnastic, it is not part of your source code. This is not a problem that both these types are mutually dependent and you cannot do much about it.

To discard generated type you can write a query like...

```
from t in Application.Types
where !t.IsGeneratedByCompiler
select t
```

...and then export part of the result to the Matrix:

[image]

Finally, I'd like to add that types being mutually dependent is not a problem in the general case. Most of well-known [GoF design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) require mutually dependent types.

The problem is when you have mutually dependent components, especially if these components are namespaces. There are [two white-books](http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx) about this topic available publicly on the NDepend web-site.

One of the case where types being mutually dependent is a problem is when base class is using derivatives (there is a default CQLinq rule [Base class should not use derivatives](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Base_class_should_not_use_derivatives.html) for that)